# Cakephp admin routing prefix not redirect to the correct prefix after login

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 admin roles (super, admin), at first login, everything works fine but after logout and login as a different admin, it redirect be to the super prefix.

Here is my app controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $helpers = array('Js', 'Session');
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'RequestHandler',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Auth' => array(
        'autoRedirect' => false,
        'loginAction' => array(
            'admin' => false,
            'super' => false,
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'dashboard',
            'admin'=> true,
            'super'=> true
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'admin' => false,
            'super' => false,
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Please login to continue.',
        'flash' => array('element' => 'flash/default', 'key' => 'auth', 'params' => array('class' => 'error', 'title' => 'Authentication Error')),
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email'
                    ),
            )
        ),
    )
);

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    # Accept if Admin
    if($user['admin']){
        return true;
    }

    # Check if current prefix is admin or physician and authenticate user
    if(isset($this->request->prefix)) {
        switch ($this->request->prefix) {
            case 'super':
                if(!$user['super']){
                    $this->Auth->authError = 'Sorry, you do not have permission to access the Manager\'s area';
                }
                return $user['super'];
                break;
             case 'admin':
                if(!$user['admin']){
                    $this->Auth->authError = 'Sorry, you do not have permission to access the Administrators\'s area';
                }else{
                    $this->layout = 'admin_layout';
                }
                return $user['admin'];
                break;
        }
    }else{
        $this->layout = 'super_layout';
        return true;
    }

    $this->Auth->authError = 'Sorry, you do not have permission to access the Admin area';
    return false;
}

public function beforefilter(){
    $this->appSettings = Configure::read('appSettings');
    $this->set('appSettings',  Configure::read('appSettings'));

    if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $this->Auth->authError = false;
    }

     if(isset($this->request->prefix)) {
        switch ($this->request->prefix) {
            case 'admin':
                $this->layout = 'admin_layout';
                $admin = true;
                break;
            case 'super':
                $this->layout = 'super_layout';
                $super = true;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

property AuthComponent::$loginRedirect

The URL (defined as a string or array) to the controller action users should be redirected to after logging in. This value will be ignored if the user has an Auth.redirect value in their session.

If you tried accessed domain.com/super/ and tried to login as an admin, cake will ignore the $loginRedirect attribute and after you login , it will try to redirect you to domain.com/super/ which is the link you tried to access at first

Comment: That works fine but after super admin role logout, and a admin login, it still shows domain.com/super